# Android getIntent().getExtras(); always null in oncreate when app is closed opened again, which extra from broadcastreceiver

Tags: android

I want to create a simple media player app, play a mp3 from service, and is success, but I want to when the music is already playing when app closed from user (onPause if I don't wrong) I want to get info extra which I send via broadcast and receive in broadcastreceive.
I always get null in oncreate when I open app again while the music running/playing.

Log.d("MyLog", "Extrafrombroadcast: "+extras); // I get my extras data.
But when I close app and open again. The app running from oncreate again. So in:
Log.d("MyLog", "Extraoncreate: "+extras); // return null.
How I get my extras data in oncreate when app closed and open again with same data as in extras in broadcast receiver?

In myactivity.class

```
public BroadcastReceiver activityReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Log.d("MyLog", "Extrafrombroadcast: "+extras);
        selectedSong = extras.getInt("selectedSongFromService");
        Serializable songStatusFromService = extras
                .getSerializable("songStatusFromService");

        songStatus = (SongStatus) songStatusFromService;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Log.d("MyLog", "Extraoncreate: "+extras);

    playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intentToService = new Intent();
                            intentToService.setAction(ACTION_STRING_SERVICE);
                            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                            extras.putInt("selectedSongFromActivity", selectedSong);
                            extras.putSerializable("songStatusFromActivity", songStatus);
                            intentToService.putExtras(extras);
                            sendBroadcast(intentToService);
        }
    });
    
}
```

In myservice.class

```
public BroadcastReceiver serviceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                selectedSong = extras.getInt("selectedSongFromActivity");
                songStatus = extras.getSerializable("songStatusFromActivity");

                sendBroadcast();
            }
        }
    };

    private void sendBroadcast() {
        Intent intentToActivity = new Intent();
        intentToActivity.setAction(ACTION_STRING_ACTIVITY);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putInt("selectedSongFromService", selectedSong);
        extras.putSerializable("songStatusFromService", songStatus);
        intentToActivity.putExtras(extras);
        sendBroadcast(intentToActivity);
    }
```

I want get my extras data because there I put position index which file mp3 selected/playing and status playing or not playing, because I want to set the seekbar in position and will be a button pause if it playing, and the button will be play if the music is being pause or stop. And go to index position selected song in list view.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a version specific Android bug where the extras of the original intent are not serialized properly during the destroy/recreate cycle.  You may need to use onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState to pass around the extras you need.  This is all off the top of my head, so I'd look into it a bit more.